# A car dealer sells 6 makes of cars in 5 colors with either standard or automatic transmissions. How many variations does the dealership offer?

Tags: combinatorics

> A car dealer sells 6 makes of cars in 5 colors with either standard or automatic transmissions. How many variations does the dealership offer?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Math-SE! That being said, you may want to read [this thread on asking good questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: I don't know how to word it but this has to do with combination. I don't understand how to different groups for this specific problem. It is a problem I was given for homework and I have done problems close to it but I don't understand this one in particular.

Comment: If I interprete it correctly then there are $5\cdot2=10$ possibilites for each car so there are $10^6$ possibilites in total

Comment: I may have understood the question wrongly though

Comment: Well, you have 6 choices for makes.  For each choice of make I have $5$ colors.  For each combo of make and color I can have 2 choices of automatic or standard.  How many differen types of cars do *you* think there are?

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's ${6}\cdot{5}\cdot{2}$ which would be $60$ different variations because you can choose from $6$ different brands, $5$ different colors, and whether to have standard or automatic transmissions (which is $2$ different choices).

Comment: Thank you so much!